# how to check if a list of keywords are present as substring/substrings within a cell please? and report back the matching substrings

Tags: excel

How do I search if an Excel cell contains word or words listed in a separate column, please?
If a substring is present, then show what that matching substring is.
If a second substring is met, then show that in the next column.

For example

Column A with raw data has these rows:

```
There is a dog A
Cat is happy
Cat and dog are both animals
Elephant is big
Happy cAt, dOg, fox, MOUSE Elephant are good
Hello dogelephantMOouse Hello Hello
```

Column B contains has the following ordered keys (in decreasing order of importance):

```
Row 1: dog
Row 2: cat
Row 3: mouse
```

Desired Columns C, D, E ... are as following:

[image]

I do not have XLOOK function.
I think the functions to use may be a combination of SEARCH, MATCH, COUNTIF, VLOOK.  But I do not know exactly how to write it up.

**QUESTION:
How do I check if a list of keywords are present as a substring/substrings in a cell, please? (columns D, E, F .. shown).**

The keywords have level of important (for example   dog and cat are both present in one cell (cell A4), but column B shows dog is more important; therefore cell C4 reports dog first, then D4 reports cat next; even though in cell A4 cat occurred before dog).

Thank you

PS: I use offline Desktop version Microsoft Excel 2019 on Windows 10 (64 bit).

ADDENDUM:

This is the output I would like:

Showing the actual matched substrings down along the row to the right.
First match is placed in column C, next match in column D so on.

[image]

Comment: I think I might have found a partial answer here:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3796-excel-check-if-cell-contains-one-of-several-values.html

Comment: Problem solved. I used these tutorials:

https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/miscellaneous/range-contains-one-of-many-substrings

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2500-excel-constant-cell-value-reference.html#:~:text=In%20the%20Formula%20Bar%2C%20put,formula%2C%20and%20then%20press%20F4.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/how-to-stop-excel-from-changing-a-range-when-you-drag-a-formula-down

https://superuser.com/questions/1284635/display-the-lines-that-meet-the-countif-criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you imagine the output looking like?
If you want to only use excel functions (ie no macros) you could do something like mapping the values to a number and adding them up:

In this i'd put your lookup table in a8:b10, and this was in b2

=IFERROR(IF(FIND($A$8,A2),$B$8,0),0)+IFERROR(IF(FIND($A$9,A2),$B$9,0),0)+IFERROR(IF(FIND($A$10,A2),$B$10,0),0)

I've mapped them to values so b2 tells you dog, b3 tells you cat, and b4 implies dog + cat

I suspect this isn't the form of output you want so maybe draw up what you want it to look like manually and i'll see if I can help further/edit this?

[image: image of shot of excel response]

Comment: Hi Jacketclarke, I have made addendum to show desired output. Macro is OK also  if I have to use it to make life easier.  However the matched substring needs to be displayed (not just how many match).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula in C2 (if you have Excel 365 current channel):

```
=LET(keys,TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$4),
     result,MAP(keys,LAMBDA(k,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(k,A2)),k,""))),
     FILTER(result,result<>"",""))
```

It transposes the keys to columns.

And then `MAP` checks per cell if the keyword is present in A2 - if not, keyword is removed.

To have a clean result - `FILTER` removes the empty results.

BTW: in your last row (Hello dogelephantMOouse Hello Hello) there is no mouse - but a typo-mouse: MOouse.

Comment: Hi Ike, thanks for picking up on the MOouse.  It's meant to be MOuse. 
I don't have Office 365.  I am using offline Desktop version of Excel 2019.